# SQL Select, selecting a row off of a column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
Division    Department  Dept. Head
1              1             Mr. Anon     
2              1              NULL 
3              1              NULL 

1              2              NULL
2              2              NULL
3              2              NULL
```

I am trying to write a query that will select rows based on conditions for the 3rd column (Dept. Head).
If there is a row in the department head that is not null (Mr. Anon) select that row.  If there are no rows in the department head with a non null value, select any row.

So out of the two groups i have in the above table, i want to select only one row from each.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL?

Comment: using 2005 Microsoft SQL

Comment: thanks to both of u, ive gotten it to work.. now i just gotta add this to a bigger picture

Answer (score 2):

```
  select division, department, depthead
    from tbl
   where depthead is not null
   union all
  select min(division) any_division, department, NULL
    from tbl
group by department
  having count(depthead) = 0;
```

Sample Data

```
create table tbl (
    division int, department int, depthead varchar(100),
    primary key(department, division));
insert into tbl values (1, 1, null);
insert into tbl values (2, 1, 'Mr Head');
insert into tbl values (3, 1, null);
insert into tbl values (1, 2, null);
insert into tbl values (2, 2, null);
insert into tbl values (3, 2, null);
```

Result:

```
division    department  depthead
----------- ----------- ------------
2           1           Mr Head
1           2           NULL
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if there were two divisions with a depthead (kind of strange to have a DEPThead column in a division table anyway)

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by department
                    order by case when depthead is not null then 1 else 2 end
                    ) as rn
        ,       yt.*
        from    YourTable yt
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35a88/1/0)